# Will CentOs 6.5 be compatible with Redhat certified motherboards?

Tags: motherboard, centos, compatibility, redhat-enterprise-linux

I had a Intel Desktop Board eb lake where it installed successfully without any problems. SO Intel discontinued that board according to the supplier and instead they gave me the newer one. Next thing I know is CentOs is unhappy with the hardware, although I couldn't pinpoint what could possibly different.

So I read CentOs derives from Redhat and I am therefore asking if the chances are good for CentOs to be compatible with their [list](https://hardware.redhat.com/list.cgi?product=Red%20Hat%20Hardware%20Certification&search_type=&component=Red%20Hat%20Enterprise%20Linux&version=5&devel_whiteboard=&devel_whiteboard_type=allwordssubstr&long_desc=&long_desc_type=allwordssubstr&internal_whiteboard=Server&internal_whiteboard=Desktop/Workstation&internal_whiteboard=Laptop&internal_whiteboard=Component/Peripheral&showall=1) of motherboards. A friend of mine also mentioned the Super Micro X10 range is a very good range for Linux distro's (incl CentOs of course), Vmware and other operating systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CentOS is binary compatible with RHEL, so for 100% if some hw run RHEL it will run CentOS too.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but would you be able to provide any resources to proof or confirm? Since this is servers I am dealing with, I simply cannot afford assuming it will work.

Comment: CentOS / FAQ / 1. What is CentOS Linux: "CentOS Linux releases are built from publicly available open source SRPMS provided by Red Hat, Inc for Red Hat Enterprise Linux." http://wiki.centos.org/FAQ/General#head-4b2dd1ea6dcc1243d6e3886dc3e5d1ebb252c194

Also take a look at CentOS / FAQ / 6. Does CentOS change the upstream Source RPMs?

No. CentOS' key mandate for our base and updates repositories is NOT extending or enhancing packages or features beyond those supplied by the upstream Source RPM's. CentOS strives intentionally to be a simple binary-functional clone for our users.

Comment: @Rudolph, CentOS is RHEL with the Red Hat branding removed.